# How to use an IF statement to ensure one is always true, and either of the others is true

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to do this in a single IF statement to avoid having duplicated code, I would like to know if it is possible to do what I want to do.

I originally had this code to run code on all categories that doesn't equal '15', Now I need it to not apply to categories 15 and 57.

Original code:

```
if ($level==1 && $category_id!=15){
```

New code (the general idea):

```
if ($level==1 && ($category_id!=15 || $category_id!=57)){
```

Edit: If downvoting, please explain why. I have tested the code above and it always returns false.

Comment: Did you try this code?

Comment: I didn't.. I thought you couldn't add sub statements in IF statements.. but Now I'm thinking if all it does is check if either a true, then it should work?

Comment: @JohnConde I just tested it, and it is always false.

Comment: @user2924019 surely its always `true` not `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code means that `if` will be true when `$level` equals to 1 and `$category_id` doesn't equal to none of 15, 57.

```
if ($level == 1 && !in_array($category_id, array(15, 57)))
```

Have a look here: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: To avoid having multiple AND statements in your IF condition it's better to use in_array() populated by the values you want to exclude.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer for this question.

Comment: I usually do if I can straight away, if not, then its the next time I am on the site.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if ($level==1 && $category_id!=15 && $category_id!=57){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use multiple and criteria:

```
if ($level==1 && $category_id!=15 && $category_id!=57){
```

The reason your current code fails (it will always return true when `$level==1`) is because `$category_id` can never be both values.

let `$category_id ==15` then the left side of the condition `($category_id!=15 || $category_id!=57)` will evaluate to false `(15 != 15) == false` so the right side will be evaluated `(15 != 57) == true` causing the overall statement to evaluate to true.

let `$category_id ==57` then the left side of the condition `($category_id!=15 || $category_id!=57)` will evaluate to true `(57 != 15) == true` so the right side is never evaluated, causing the overall statement to evaluate to true.